# php sql subquery not giving any result, but sql subquery is

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

**Code:**

```
$query  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zoekkoper WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM USERS WHERE email='$session_email')");

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
table output...
}
```

Have 2 tables:

1) users (id)

2) zoekkopers (id, user_id)

Want to select results from table 'zoekkopers' with a match from table 'users' id. id and user_id have the same value in both tables. The current logged in user should only see his own added values. 
I tried the sql in my phpadmin and that gives me the correct results but I'm failing making it work in php. If I delete the WHERE part then I get all the results value from all the users in my database, just want it more specific for each user.

$session_email is the current logged in user.

Also tried this sql in PHP:

```
"SELECT * FROM zoekkoper JOIN users ON (user_id=id) WHERE email='$session_email'");
```

**PHPMYADMIN:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `zoekkoper` 
WHERE user_id = ( 
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE email =  '...' )
```

Comment: Utilize mysql error display, so you can tell if you have sql errors.

Comment: But you may want to change `user_id =` to `user_id IN` ... or just turn to JOIN syntax instead of nested queries.

Comment: "$session_email is the current logged in user" Have you done `var_dump($session_email);` to _confirm_ that the value is what you expect it to be at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to JOIN like below:-

```
$query  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zoekkoper JOIN users ON zoekkoper.user_id= users.id WHERE users.email='$session_email'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: I support the join method over nested query method. And note in this answer, the `table.` prefix for fields is why the original attempt would fail, and why this answer's sql is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `IN` for where clause, because the subselect may return more than one results;

```
$query  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM zoekkoper WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM USERS WHERE email='$session_email')");
```